Unable to generate ef-core migration when running "update-database" command from VS 2022. Error Number:18456, State 1 Login failed for user
I am working on .Net 8 Web Api project with EF Core and microservices architecture. I am using Azure Free subscription and using Azure Sql Server and using Azure Data Studio on my machine instead of SSMS.
When I ran migration to create the first database it created using add-migration
and update-database command. However when I tried to create my second database for another microservice, it gives me below error when I run update-database command:
ClientConnectionId:16cc642d-fd94-4313-87b8-bfe22161fd92
Error Number:18456,State:1,Class:20
Login failed for user 'admin-napsterj'.
[VS 2022 Migration command error] (https://i.sstatic.net/IDvLfWkS.png)
Azure Portal - SQL Server 
Please advise and help. Let me know if you need any other information from my side.
Before posting here I already checked the below from my side:

I checked my connection string, username, password, authentication type which is SQL    Authentication which is all correct. But not able to understand why it does not work ? I checked my permissions on Azure Portal.

I tried reading on google, reddit and stackoverflow but did not find same issue faced by others.



When you asked your question, you were told "Please make sure to post code and errors as text directly to the question (and not as images), and format them appropriately." Please follow the instructions when posting your questions, as otherwise you are likely to receive down and/or close votes; meaning your question is far less likely to be answered.

Hi Abhishek, please try to check your firewall rules, you can allow all ip for testing.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.


ClientConnectionId:16cc642d-fd94-4313-87b8-bfe22161fd92 Error Number:18456,State:1,Class:20 Login failed for user 'admin-napsterj'.

Ensure you have provided correct credentials to access the database. You have provided connection string in correct format. To find connection string go to Azure SQL db page,  go to Connection strings tab, you will find the connection string as shown below:

You are getting loin failed error, even though you have provided correct credentials, and correct connection string format then follow below instructions:
To use dotnet ef on command line the package you need is  Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.Dotnet  It is dotnet CLI tool so you need to manually edit csproj file to install it. Adding following code in Flexure.Domain.csproj will give you  dotnet ef
<ItemGroup>
   <DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.Dotnet" Version="<version>" />
</ItemGroup>

Along with that before staring the migration run below command:
add-migration Init

After that, run update-database command, it will run successfully without any error. For more information you can refer to this.
